# Changing Windows metadata of JPEG file via BitmapMetadata clears non-specified metadata

Tags: c#, bitmap, metadata, jpeg

Using the code below based on the example in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.datetaken?view=netcore-3.1) to set DateTaken for a JPEG file from a Windows Forms application (not UWP) I find that the specified value is correctly set but many metadata fields not set (eg Tags, Title, Subject) are cleared. How can I set DateTaken and leave other fields unchanged?

```
public static void SetDateTaken(string sFile, DateTime DateTaken, bool bShowError = false)
    {
        try
        {

            FileStream stream3 = new FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open);
            BitmapMetadata myBitmapMetadata = new BitmapMetadata("jpg");
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder3 = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

            myBitmapMetadata.DateTaken = DateTaken.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

            //Create a new frame that is identical to the one
            //from the original image, except for the new metadata.

            BitmapCreateOptions createOptions = new BitmapCreateOptions();
            string sTempFile = sFile + ".tmp3";
            System.IO.File.Copy(sFile, sTempFile, true);
            using (Stream tempStream = System.IO.File.Open(sTempFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                BitmapDecoder decoder2 = BitmapDecoder.Create(tempStream, createOptions, BitmapCacheOption.None);
                encoder3.Frames.Add(
                BitmapFrame.Create(
                decoder2.Frames[0],
                decoder2.Frames[0].Thumbnail,
                myBitmapMetadata,
                decoder2.Frames[0].ColorContexts));


                encoder3.Save(stream3);
                stream3.Close();
            }
            // Delete the temp file
            System.IO.File.Delete(sTempFile);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Common.LogError("SetDateTaken Error", Ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.keywords?view=netcore-3.1) are to be trusted there can only be 15 properties; I gues you need to read and set each of them.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I was able to get the BitmapMetadata from the input file as shown below. The code now preserves all existing Windows (and EXIF, XMP, and IPTC) metadata but updates Windows DateTaken. It's necessary to reset Modified, Created and Last Accessed dates to those in the original file as these are all set to time of action otherwise.

```
       public static void SetDateTaken(string sFile, DateTime DateTaken, DateTime Created, DateTime Accessed, bool bShowError = false)
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapCreateOptions createOptions = new BitmapCreateOptions();
            BitmapMetadata myBitmapMetadata2 = new BitmapMetadata("jpg"); ;

            using (Stream sourceStream = System.IO.File.Open(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // Check source is has valid frames
                BitmapDecoder sourceDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(sourceStream, createOptions, BitmapCacheOption.None); 
                if (sourceDecoder.Frames[0] != null && sourceDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata != null)
                {
                    // Get a clone copy of the metadata
                    myBitmapMetadata2 = sourceDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata.Clone() as BitmapMetadata;
                 }
                else throw new System.Exception("File "+ sFile + " does not have valid frames");
            }
           
            FileStream stream3 = new FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open);
            BitmapMetadata myBitmapMetadata = myBitmapMetadata2;
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder3 = new JpegBitmapEncoder();              

            myBitmapMetadata.DateTaken = DateTaken.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

            //Create a new frame that is identical to the one
            //from the original image, except for the new metadata.

            string sTempFile = sFile + ".tmp3";
            System.IO.File.Copy(sFile, sTempFile, true);
            using (Stream tempStream = System.IO.File.Open(sTempFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                BitmapDecoder decoder2 = BitmapDecoder.Create(tempStream, createOptions, BitmapCacheOption.None);
                encoder3.Frames.Add(
                BitmapFrame.Create(
                decoder2.Frames[0],
                decoder2.Frames[0].Thumbnail,
                myBitmapMetadata,
                decoder2.Frames[0].ColorContexts));


                encoder3.Save(stream3);
                stream3.Close();
            }
            // Delete the temp file
            System.IO.File.Delete(sTempFile);

            // reset dates

            System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime(sFile, DateTaken);
            System.IO.File.SetCreationTime(sFile, Created);
            System.IO.File.SetLastAccessTime(sFile, Accessed);

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Common.LogError("SetDateTaken Error", Ex);
        }
    }enter code here
```